# Reference Date 2 Months Prior Access SQL

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, join

I'm doing a Self Join, but having trouble doing it with dates.  I have a date column, mm/dd/yyyy in intervals of a month (1/1/2006, 2/1/2006,...) and a number column of a variety of numbers.  See code below...

```
SELECT t.ADate,
       Sum(pre.liquid)/3 AS IP90
  FROM [Table2] t
  LEFT JOIN [Table2] pre ON pre.ADate >= (t.ADate -3)
   AND pre.ADate <= t.ADate
 GROUP BY t.ADate;
```

I'm taking the average of the records 2 months prior to the current date and the current date. So, for 5/1/2006 I want the average amount of liquid for 3/1/2006, 4/1/2006, and 5/1/2006.  How can I do that in my code? Thank you.

Comment: is `3/1/2006` `January 3` or `March 1`? It affect what `t.ADate -3` does versus what it's expected to do.

Comment: 3/1/2006 would be March 1.

Answer (score 1):

Can you specify the dates in the query? Also I believe there is an average function in Access.

```
SELECT AVG(pre.liquid) As IP90
FROM [Table2] t
LEFT JOIN [Table2] pre
  ON pre.ADate = t.ADate
WHERE t.ADate BETWEEN '3/1/2006' AND '5/1/2006';
```

Note you might have to give the dates a bit of leeway depending on the date values.

Comment: I was able to get it to run for a short list of entries (I have over 200,000 entries).  I used the AVG function which I think helped speed it up.  I actually just changed my ON statement to show ON pre.ADate >= (t.ADate - 61)
   AND ...  By subtracting by 61 it looked back 61 days (two months).  Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: @user3827129 You may also consider that 3 months isn't always 61 days. Maybe `DateAdd("m", -3, t.ADate)` will prove useful.